# Angular dynamic form is not working in IE

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular 1.6 in our application. We have a dynamic form directive that is not working in Internet Explorer 11 (IE-11). Html form components while loading in the screen blocks the screen because those components are not dynamically created.How can I make it work?

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: 1. explain in detail what the expected outcome should be; 2. share your code; 3. briefly explain the problema you are facing; 4. relate back to the code as to have a clear understading of where to begin investigating; 5. explain what you have tried to solve the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dynamic form will not work properly with IE11.It can be explicitly made to work with IE.

Create explicit html components through your controller js.

```
    document.createElement('ng-include');
    document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng-view');
    document.createElement('ng-form');
    document.createElement('dynamic-form');

    // Optionally these for CSS
    document.createElement('ng:include');
    document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
    document.createElement('ng:view');
    document.createElement('ng:form');

    // IE doesn't always run the bootstrap on its own...
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document.documentElement);
    });
```

Explicitly you need to do some modifications in your dynamic-form.js file.Bypass the element when it is undefined or null by adding a null/undefined check

```
 while (!angular.equals(iterElem.parent(), $document) && !angular.element(iterElem.parent()[0])== undefined || !angular.element(iterElem.parent()[0])== null) {
//logic will come here for iteration
}
```